# Jquery Validation Plugin - Validate Fields Being Added

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need help on jQuery Validation.  Basically, I have couple static fields and the validation work fine when I try to submit the form.  However, I have a dynamical add/remove field, which I don't know who to capture the elementID and validate it.  Lets me explain the problem.

I have 3 static fields Cost, Type, and Region. and this below validation works correctly that those fields.

```
$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        Cost: {
            currency: true
        },

        Type: {
            required: true  
        },

        Region: {
            required: true  
        }

    }
});
```

Now, I have a button to add (also have remove option by the row) for the textbox, and this adding feature is working fine also.

```
<input type="button" name="AddIssue" id="AddIssue" value="Add Issue"  class="button2"/>
```

When the AddIssue button clicked, the following textbox will be added, and the elementID keeps increasing for each textbox is being added as below example.

```
<input type="text"  id="Issue_1" name="Issue_1" size="5" value="" />
<input type="text"  id="Issue_2" name="Issue_2" size="5" value="" />
<input type="text"  id="Issue_3" name="Issue_3" size="5" value="" />
<input type="text"  id="Issue_4" name="Issue_4" size="5" value="" />
```

I would like to include in the jQuery validation to go through any elementID like "Issue_", and check to see if the value is NOT blank. How can I do this?

Please help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `required` class to the new elements:

```
<input type="text" id="Issue_1" name="Issue_1" size="5" value="" class="required" />
```

jquery-validate` automatically recognizes class names that match its validation rules and applies them.

Comment: That sure beats using `jQuery.validator.addClassRules()` can you link to it in the docs. I did not see that mentioned.

Comment: I don't know where this is stated in the current documentation -- it's been completely rearranged since I learned how to use the plugin a couple of years ago. At that time, many of the examples used classes.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, your solution is simple and work, but I forgot to mention that I want to require user to add least one textbox (Issue_1). Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't think the validation plugin can do that by itself. It can only validate the contents of fields, but they have to exist in the first place. You could code your field addition/deletion code to not allow removing the last field.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is [JQuery Validate Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/), I think the below will be the best way to approach it in a manner that allows for the input's to be dynamically generated, and if you wish to apply custom messages, and/or additional options to the rule used.

If you simply want it to be required `class="required"` will do that as listed in the other answer.

**[PER THE DOCS](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules)**

> Example: Add a new compound rule called “name”, replacing
>   class=”required” minlength=”2″ with class=”name”.

**Current CODE**

```
$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        Cost: {
            currency: true
        },

        Type: {
            required: true  
        },

        Region: {
            required: true  
        }

    }
});
```

**ADDED CODE**

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules("issue", {
  required: true,
  minlength: 2
});
```

With that in place, we can add a class customer to all customer fields and be done with it:

So your inputs will need to have a class applied like so.

```
<input type="text"  id="Issue_1" name="Issue_1" size="5" value="" class="issue"/>
<input type="text"  id="Issue_2" name="Issue_2" size="5" value="" class="issue"/>
<input type="text"  id="Issue_3" name="Issue_3" size="5" value="" class="issue"/>
<input type="text"  id="Issue_4" name="Issue_4" size="5" value="" class="issue"/>
```

Then you can add any input you want with that class and it will validate based on the "issue"  `ClassRules`.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GaYSc/2/)**

Comment: Is there a way while validating I can loop through all elementIDs and capture any ID starts with "Issue_". If there is nothing found, then prompt user need to add at least one?

Comment: I just stepped away from my pc, but I don't think you can validate against an input's existence. There may be a way to add a callback function or something via the API. I will check when I get home and update.